# SQL query not updating table when row is changed

Tags: c#, mysql

I am having a small problem with my SQL query that is best explained through an example:

**1) If `booking.status` is set to open, then it is counted when the method is run and presented in the datatable. Let's take `plot_id=15`, as you can see here it appears 3 times in the table.**

[image]

[image]

**2) As a result, the change will be reflected in `plot.jobs`**

[image]

**3) But in a case where `booking.status` is updated, then it is no longer counted when the method is run, or presented in the datatable. This is expected.**

[image]

[image]

**4) If it doesn't appear in the list, then it means the `plot.plot_id=15` should be 0... why is it still 3 in `plot.jobs`**

[image]

I think I am missing out an SQL query in the `if (dtCounts.Rows.Count > 0) {...}` conditional. Problem is I have no idea where to start implementing it. Can anyone please point me in the right direction? How can I account for instances where `booking.status` is changed, when updating `plot.jobs`?

This is my code so far: http://pastebin.com/pYu17aVR

(sorry, for some reason S/O won't let me paste the code into the answer, it keeps returning an error message)

Comment: The code sample you provided does not show any updates to `booking.status` happening. Where does that happen?  ... you'll need to make `plot.jobs` update when `booking.status` changes. either in the C# "business logic" (??) or in the SQL.

Comment: @G.Cito - it takes place in another method. I can post it up for you, if you want to see it. I've posted it up at http://pastebin.com/B2D29azv, but please note that the SQL has yet to parameterised, so it is still in the early stages of development.  `booking.status` is updated at the `Allocate jobs to bids` section i.e. `foreach (BidList t in bidList) { .... }`. I hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, I don't see the need for looping at all.  Instead, you can combine the queries into one, which can handle the nulls as well:

```
update plot p 
inner join (
  select sum(case when status = 'open' then 1 else 0 end) cnt, plot_id
  from booking
  group by plot_id
  ) p2 on p.plot_id = p2.plot_id
set p.jobs = p2.cnt
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4768c/1)

There are a couple things to be aware of -- what should happen if no data exists in the booking table for that plot_id?  What about new plots being added?

Comment: There is an additional clause I left out, have a look at else `if ((dtCounts.Rows.Count == 0)) {...}` at http://pastebin.com/D3CgW6iB. I think that this is meant to do the job. Btw I am not sure how your SQL query would fit in the context of my code. Where would I put it and how would it change things?

Comment: Btw does the clause satisfy the the requirement you just pointed out i.e. `what should happen if no data exists in the booking table for that plot_id?`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if i understood what you want to do excactly.

Have you ever thought to implement a trigger on update of booking status?

```
CREATE
    [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
    TRIGGER trigger_name
    trigger_time trigger_event
    ON tbl_name FOR EACH ROW
    trigger_body

trigger_time: { BEFORE | AFTER }

trigger_event: { INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE }
```

Comment: Now more than one person has noticed. Can you post the code that does that?

Comment: I've posted it up at http://pastebin.com/B2D29azv - it's just at this point the SQL queries have not beem parameterised yet, so please bear in mind that this is a clean up activity that I have planned for this weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Your update statement given in the paste bin listing at line 12-17 is conditional to `booking.plot_id is NULL` (l.17).

Comment: Yes, it needs to be conditional to `status='open'` in order to update `plot.jobs`, which provides a summary of all the jobs with the `status='open'`. My dilemma is that I am not sure how to account for then the status changes. The current query does not recognise the row anymore, and as result does not update the column. So for instance, if 2 rows had `status='allocated'` then it would still report back as 3 instead of 1. Hopefully, it make sense now.

Comment: Please have a look at @G. Cito's comment, he raised a very good point about something I overlooked in the question. I've posted the code that handles the `status='allocated'` at pastebin.com/B2D29azv.